Is there a Hyperbolic Rotation Formula using Hyperbolic Quaternions?
I've been trying to find a formula for Hyperbolic Rotations using Hyperbolic Quaternions so maybe some sort of equivalent to the formula for Spatial Rotations with Ordinary Quaternions where $$q \to QqQ^{-1}.$$
I've already found out that there is an equivalent of the complex number formula for 2D rotations in the unit circle which is the formula with associative Split-Complex Numbers for 2D Hyperbolic Rotations.
One reason I could think of why there might be no such formula with Hyperbolic Quaternions is that Hyperbolic Rotations are Linear Transformations and Hyperbolic Quaternions are not associative in general. However, I'm new to the requirements of Linear Transformations, so I'm not sure if this idea is true.
Now my question is if there is such a formula with Hyperbolic Quaternions for general Hyperbolic Rotations and if no, would my reason be a correct answer why there's no such formula or not?

What do you mean be "hyperbolic rotations"? Do you mean a rotation in hyperbolic space, or a Lorentz boost? These are quite different, as Lorentz boosts actually correspond to translations in hyperbolic space. Rotations in 3D hyperbolic space are, in a certain sense, also represented by the usual quaternions just like in 3D Euclidean space.

What I meant with hyperbolic rotations is that a 2D (or 3D)-point on a hyperbola is rotated by an hyperbolic angle and the rotated point lies on that hyperbola as well. Considering Special Relativity, the invariance of the distances is "fulfilled". I'd read on that the following website:  http://www.physicsinsights.org/hyperbolic_rotations.html . So I'm not able to answer your question but you might want to take a look at that. To rephrase my original question: Can such a rotation formula be found for these hyperbolic rotations with hyperbolic quaternions and can it be applied on L-Boosts?

Ok, so you're interested in Lorentz boosts. They are often called "hyperbolic rotations" for the obvious analogy with usual rotations, but as I said it is a somewhat curious fact that if you try to apply them to hyperbolic space you get translations! In any case, the wiki article shows how you can use hyperbolic quaternions to perform Lorentz boosts, but this is a one-sided action...

If you want a double-sided action like quaternions, then we have to use biquaternions instead, though making a proper analogy with quaternions-as-rotations is somewhat involved. Is that something you would be interested in?

Yes, I've already come across the biquaternions and found out how to apply them for Lorentz Transformations. Back to the Hyperbolic Quaternions: So you can only apply them for the special case where you have a 1+1D system (with a boost in any 3D-direction) but not in general when you have a 1+3D system with a boost in any 3D-direction? If true, would you mind taking a look at what @Roland F meant in the comment below? I thought what he meant is that there is a formula for the general case.

A boost is determined by a "hyperbolic angle" (rapidity) and a time-like plane of rotation $P$ (meaning it contains time-like and space-like vectors). The boost acts as the identity on $P^\perp$, so boosting within a single plane $(1{+}1)$D plane $P$ is enough. Examining the wiki article more closely, I think things actually work out if you use a two-sided action $q \mapsto e^{ar/2}qe^{ar/2}$ with $q$ an arbitrary hyperbolic quaternion representing a 4-vector and with associativity a non-issue for this form, but I'm not 100% sure.

Ok, I've tried it out for $q \mapsto e^{ar/2}qe^{ - ar/2}$ for a special case and it seemed to work, I'll try it out for the general case tomorrow and compare it with the Biquaternion Lorentz Transformation (setting the angle of the spatial rotation to 0). I'll then edit this post and update it with the result.

That second $e^{ar/2}$ wasn't a typo. You're going to want $e^{ar/2}qe^{ar/2}$ because $r$ anticommutes with the imaginary hyperbolic quaternions in its orthogonal complement, and when $q = t + xr$ you (hopefully) recover $e^{ar/2}qe^{ar/2} = e^{ar}q$. I say "hopefully" because I'm not sure how the non-associativity plays out.

OK, so I obtain a similar general form but not the exact same form when comparing with the Biquaternion formula: For $e^{ar/2}qe^{ar/2}$, I get for the new x'-coordinate $x' = \cosh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^{2}x + 2\sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cosh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}x_v c t +\sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2 (x_v ^2 x + y_v ^2 x + z_v ^2 x)$ with $x_v, y_v$ and $z_v$ being the coefficients of $r$. Regarding the biquaternion form, the $\cosh^2$ and $\sinh\cosh$ terms are the same, the $\sinh^2$ term changes to $\sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2(x_v ^2 x + 2x_v y_v y + 2x_v z_v z - y_v ^2 x - z_V ^2 x)$.

The y'- and z'-coordinates follow the same pattern. Interestingly, the ct'-coordinate of the Biquaternion formula and of the Hyperbolic quaternion formula have the same form, namely $ct' = \cosh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2 ct + 2\sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cosh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(x_v x + y_v y + z_v z) + ct \sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}^2(x_v ^2 + y_v ^2 + z_v ^2)$.

The split quaternions are isomorphic to the even-grade sub-algebra of the Clifford algebra of the quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$. Take a look at Clifford/geometric algebra more generally. It works in any dimension.

In the hyperbolic quaternions, the product of two vectors (in ${\rm span}\{{\bf i},{\bf j},{\bf k}\}$) satisfies
$$ {\bf uv} \,=\, {\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}+{\bf u}\times{\bf v}. $$
Testing alternativity yields
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
 ({\bf uv}){\bf u} & = & {\bf v} \\[5pt]
 {\bf u}({\bf vu}) & = & {\bf v}_{\|}-{\bf v}_{\perp}
\end{array} $$
and we get the familiar hyperbolic Euler's formula
$$ \exp(r{\bf u})=\cosh(r)+\sinh(r)\,{\bf u}. $$
From this, four candidates come to mind to investigate:
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
 (e^{r{\bf u}}{\bf v})e^{r{\bf u}}\phantom{{}^-} & = & \sinh(2r)\,{\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}+\cosh(2r)\,{\bf v} \\[5pt]
 e^{r{\bf u}}({\bf v}e^{r{\bf u}})\phantom{{}^-} & = & \sinh(2r)\,{\bf u}\cdot{\bf v}+\cosh(2r)\,{\bf v}_{\|}+{\bf v}_{\perp} \\[5pt]
 (e^{r{\bf u}}{\bf v})e^{-r{\bf u}} & = & {\bf v}+\sinh(2r)\,{\bf u}\times{\bf v} \\[5pt]
 e^{r{\bf u}}({\bf v}e^{-r{\bf u}}) & = & \cosh(2r)\,{\bf v}_{\|}+{\bf v}_{\perp}+\sinh(2r)\, {\bf u}\times{\bf v}
\end{array} $$
Only the second is a hyperbolic rotation, specifically in the ${\bf u}1$-plane (leaving the complement invariant).

Still, this is a less useful of modelling orthogonal transformations of (2+1)D space. Indeed, the third candidate above shows the norm is not multiplicative, even if you try a (3+1)D norm to ensure $|\exp(r{\bf u})|$ is a constant function of $r$.
The appropriate venue for (2+1)D rotations is the split quaternions, where you can do the usual conjugation to get (2+1)D isometries, which parallels the situation for 3D rotations from quaternions. Note exponentiating pure imaginaries - i.e. (2+1)D vectors - yields either Euclidean or Hyperbolic rotations depending on if the vectors are positive or negative. Also, you can get (2+2)D rotations from bimultiplications of split quaternions, just as you can get 4D rotations from bimultiplications of quaternions.
Note the split quaternions $\Bbb H'\cong M_2(\Bbb R)$ are a real subalgebra of the biquaternions, i.e. the complexified quaternions $\Bbb H\otimes\Bbb C\cong M_2(\Bbb C)$, and I wouldn't be surprised if physicists liked to model them this way (I assume that's the gist of Roland's answer, I only skimmed it).

The lowest dimensional representation of the Lorentz group in 4-d with metric $G$:  $$\Lambda \in \  \mathcal{ SO}(3,1) , \quad  \Lambda^T G \Lambda = G,\quad   (\Lambda \mathbf x)^T\  G \  (\Lambda \mathbf y)= \mathbf x^T \ G \ \mathbf y$$  is  $$ S\in \mathcal {SL}(2,\mathbb C) , \  \det S=1 $$.
Boosts in the plane spanned of the t-axis and a 3-d euclidean  unit vector $\vec n $ are represented by Pauli matrices $\mathbb 1, \sigma_k $
$$S=e^{\frac{u}{2} \ \sum_k n_k \sigma_k },  |\vec n| =1 , \det S = 1 $$
4-vectors are represented regularly in the real part of the Lie-algebra
$$X  =  t \ \mathbb \sigma_0 \ + \ \sum x_k \sigma_k $$
The trigonometry becomes simple by
$$\sigma_i\ \sigma_k \ + \ \sigma_k \ \sigma_i\  = \ 2\ \delta_{ik},  \quad (\vec b \cdot \vec \sigma)^2 \ = \ |b|^2 ,  \quad e^{ \vec b \vec \sigma} =   \cosh b + \sinh b\  \frac{\vec b}{|b|} \cdot \vec \sigma $$
Finally replace
$$(i,j,k) \ = \sqrt{-1} (\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3) $$
It's this strange incidence, that time can be represented by a scalar together with the quaternion algebra, that made formaulation of Maxwell's equation in Hamilton's quaternions  possible and on their basis universal Newtonian time suspicious.
So your question: Yes, look at the first papers of Maxwell, the complete theory of the linear representations of the Lorentz group by  Pauli, Weyl, Dirac and Naimark.

Thank you a lot for responding. Would it be possible to add the formula for Hyperbolic Quaternions so as to clarify it for me? Because I don't understand how I should find said formula using the context from above as from my understanding, this seems to apply for regular Hamilton Quaternions but not for Hyperbolic Quaternions. I would be interested in how to apply this Hyperbolic Quaternion formula (if it exists) in Lorentz-Boosts, though.

The confusion seems  to stem from the fact, that quaternions are an extension of the complex numbers to a non-commutative  product. Therefore I write $\sqrt{-1}$ instead of i. The hyperbolic base is simpliy $$\sqrt(-1)\ i, \ \sqrt(-1)\ j ,  \ \sqrt(-1)\ k$$ such that their square is 1 yielding hyprbolicas instead of trigonometrics for rotations.

I'm sorry for asking again, but could you please add the rotation formula for Hyperbolic Quaternions (not Biquaternions, but Hyperbolic Quaternions defined as $q = a + bi + cj + dk$ with $i^2 = +1, j^2 = +1, k^2 = +1$) that can be used for Lorentz Boosts? I haven't found the formula for the general case yet, apart from the special case which is also mentioned here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_quaternion#Discussion
